# HttpWebRequest - How to set variable dynamically into this body

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need help please.
I have my body that works fine with data before compiling it.

```
Dim body As String = "{""travelForm"":[{""title"":""IT Unix 4"",""description"":""<p>Hello fjdsbfjsdhfkjn,vxnc bx vxnodjosidfjlkj kjk sds iufsyiufshkjdjxfoksjdkjfsiodhfsdhfsudhfskjdlfksjlfsjdkfhkjhjk hj hdkjfhksjdhfjkh kjh skjdhfkjsdhfkj hkjsdhfskjdskh jhsjdhfkjshdfjsdhkjfsdhkhsdkjsdhskjhfskjdhjshjdhfskjhskdhfkjdhfj hkjshdfsd</p>"",""phone"":""0199654128"",""categoryfont"":7459250,""categoryClass"":""Toyota"",""DataCategory"":100,""where"":{""latitude"":-33.8659683,""longitude"":18.534443499999952,""radius"":5000},""categoryAttributes"":[],""imageWeb"":[""c:\mypict100.JPG?set_id=8800005007""]}]}"
```

but when I try to set variable dinamycally (Form3.txtbx_title.Text) like below, it doesn't work.

```
Dim body As String = "{""travelForm"":[{""title"":"&Form3.txtbx_title.Text&",""description"":""<p>Hello fjdsbfjsdhfkjn,vxnc bx vxnodjosidfjlkj kjk sds iufsyiufshkjdjxfoksjdkjfsiodhfsdhfsudhfskjdlfksjlfsjdkfhkjhjk hj hdkjfhksjdhfjkh kjh skjdhfkjsdhfkj hkjsdhfskjdskh jhsjdhfkjshdfjsdhkjfsdhkhsdkjsdhskjhfskjdhjshjdhfskjhskdhfkjdhfj hkjshdfsd</p>"",""phone"":""0199654128"",""categoryfont"":7459250,""categoryClass"":""Toyota"",""DataCategory"":100,""where"":{""latitude"":-33.8659683,""longitude"":18.534443499999952,""radius"":5000},""categoryAttributes"":[],""imageWeb"":[""c:\mypict100.JPG?set_id=8800005007""]}]}"
```

Please see full code below

```html
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.IO.Compression

Imports System.Net.WebUtility


Module PostTravelForm

    Public logincookiePost As CookieContainer
    Dim logincookstring As String

    Dim theWantedString As String

    'Calls request functions sequentially.
    Sub MakeRequests3()
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse
        Dim responseText As String

        If Request_www_germany_com(response) Then
            'Success, possibly use response.
            responseText = ReadResponse(response)

            response.Close()
        Else
            'Failure, cannot use response.
        End If
    End Sub

    'Returns the text contained in the response.  For example, the page HTML.  Only handles the most common HTTP encodings.
    Public Function ReadResponse(response As HttpWebResponse) As String
        Using responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()
            Dim streamToRead As Stream = responseStream
            If response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip") Then
                streamToRead = New GZipStream(streamToRead, CompressionMode.Decompress)
            ElseIf response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("deflate") Then
                streamToRead = New DeflateStream(streamToRead, CompressionMode.Decompress)
            End If

            Using streamReader = New StreamReader(streamToRead, Encoding.UTF8)
                Return streamReader.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
 
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Tries to request the URL: https://www.travel.com/postad/create
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="response">After the function has finished, will possibly contain the response to the request.</param>
    ''' <returns>True if the request was successful; false otherwise.</returns>
 
    Private Function Request_www_germany_com(ByRef response As HttpWebResponse) As Boolean
        response = Nothing

        Try
            'Create request to URL.
            Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://www.travel.com/api/postad/create"), HttpWebRequest)
            Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer

            'Set request headers.
            request.KeepAlive = True
            request.Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
            request.Headers.Add("Origin", "https://www.travel.com")
            request.Headers.Add("x-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest")
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"

            request.CookieContainer = logincookiePost

            request.ContentType = "application/json"
            request.Referer = "https://www.travel.com/post"
            request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate, br")
            request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.8")

            'Set request method
            request.Method = "POST"

            ' Disable 'Expect: 100-continue' behavior. More info: http://haacked.com/archive/2004/05/15/http-web-request-expect-100-continue.aspx
            request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = False

            Console.WriteLine(Form3.txtbx_title.Text & " Test !!!!!!!!!!!!")

            Dim txtbx As String = "<p>CISCO Senior Network Engineer</p>"

            'Set request body.
           
            Dim body As String = "{""ads"":[{""title"":""…" + txtbx + "…"",""description"":""<p>" + Form3.txtbx_descript.Text.Replace("""", "\""") + "</p>"",""phone"":""0799654128"",""categoryId"":9250,""categoryName"":""Computer Operators"",""parentCategory"":8,""location"":{""latitude"":-33.8659683,""longitude"":18.534443499999952,""radius"":2000},""categoryAttributes"":[],""imageUrls"":[""https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjAwWDgwMA==/z/~qIAAOSwU8hY75kG/$_1.PNG?set_id=8800005007""]}]}"


            Dim postBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body)
            request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length
            Dim stream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
            stream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length)
            stream.Close()

            'Get response to request.
            response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Catch e As WebException
            'ProtocolError indicates a valid HTTP response, but with a non-200 status code (e.g. 304 Not Modified, 404 Not Found)
            If e.Status = WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError Then
                response = DirectCast(e.Response, HttpWebResponse)
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Catch e As Exception
            If response IsNot Nothing Then
                response.Close()
            End If
            Return False
        End Try

        Return True
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: _"It doesn't work"_ is a very vague problem description. What does/doesn't happen? Is `Form3` opened by calling the default instance (`Form3.Show()`), or is it opened using `New Form3` and then calling `.Show()`?

Comment: From3.txtbx_title.Text only contains a string. Form3 is the main Form. I also tried the below    Dim txtbx As String = "CISCO Senior Network Engineer"    Dim body As String = "{""travelForm"":[{""title"":""IT Unix 4"","& txtbx &":""<p>Hello fjdsbfjsdhfkjn,vxnc bx vxnodjosidfjlkj kjk sds iufsyiufshkjdjxfoksjdkjhkjshdfsd</p>"",""phone"":""0199654128"",""categoryfont"":7459250,""categoryClass"":""Toyota"",""DataCategory"":100,""where"":{""latitude"":-33.8659683,""longitude"":18.534443499999952,""radius"":5000},""categoryAttributes"":[],""imageWeb"":[""c:\mypict100.JPG?set_id=8800005007""]}]}"

Comment: `Form3.txtbx_title.Text` **can only** contain a string! He asked _**what**_ it contains (what its value is), not _**what type**_ it contains/is. -- Yet again, please define _"it doesn't work"_.

Comment: Its value is "CISCO Senior Network Engineer".   "it doesn't work" means that the HttpWebRequest doesn't post data.

Comment: How can you tell it doesn't post the data? If it's the posting that doesn't work then why don't you show us that code instead? We don't know what you use this string for, please show us all necessary code to reproduce the problem in a simple manner.

Comment: Sorry for the delay reply. It DOES post data if I use the first statement with the data inside. If I use the second statement with a variable it does post data.  The problem is only with the "body" line. !!!

Comment: Sorry for the delay reply. It DOES post data if I use the first statement with the data inside. If I use the second statement with a variable it does NOT post data.  The problem is only in the "body" line. !!!

Answer (score 1):

If you study the [JSON syntax](http://json.org/), you will find that all object keys must be strings. That means, the keys must be properly quoted in doublequotes (`"`). Therefore,

```
{ CISCO Senior Network Engineer: "<p>Hello…</p>" }
```

is invalid JSON, while

```
{ "CISCO Senior Network Engineer": "<p>Hello…</p>" }
```

is valid JSON.

Your issue appears to be that you're not quoting the key.

**P.S.:** Please be aware that it is not enough to simply surround your `Form3.txtbx_title.Text` with doublequotes. You need to ensure that if the user entered text containing one or more doublequotes, each of these must be escaped by prefixing it with a `\` character.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I really know that I have to put double quotes for string. But my concern is I must load data dynamically. so I have to work with variable like the following : `Dim myVariable As String = "CISCO Senior Network Engineer" Dim body As String = "{""travelForm"":[{""title"":"& myVariable &",""description"":""<p>Hello fjdsbfj iufsfsd</p>"",""phone"":""01​8"",""catfont""‌​:7459250,""categoryC‌​lass"":""Toyota"",""‌​DataCat"":100,"‌​"where"":{""latitude‌​"":-33.8,""lon‌​git"":18.5,""radius"":5‌​0},""categoryAttri‌​"":[],""imageWe‌​b"":[""c:\mypict10.‌​JPG?set_id=88""]}]}"
`

Comment: `"…" + myVariable + "…"` => `"…""" + myVariable.Replace("""", "\""") + """…"`

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOOO MUCHHHHHHH  Mr stakx !!!  I used the second one as my variable is a string so it needs to contain any characters including quotes and whatever and worked fine.   Whether I use the second one, so I don't need to care about the user input anymore?  or some characters shouldn't be entered by the user?  I appreciated your Help Sir.

Comment: I would recommend that you go to [json.org](http://json.org) and study what valid JSON looks like. Then you think about what kinds of user input could lead to *invalid* JSON, given your current program logic. For example, think about what happens when the user enters a single backslash ( \ ). Does it need to be escaped or not? What if you have a multi-line text input field and the input text contains a line break? Do you need to transform that to `\n` or not? etc.

Comment: Thanks, will think about it later. By the way, in my variable, I added a mix of characters and number ( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ) but it couldn't post data. Why?

Comment: How would I know? You never showed us *how* you are posting data. Please take the comments, downvotes, and close votes to your question seriously and edit your question so that we're seeing what exactly you're actually doing / trying to do.

Comment: I added the full code to my first post. What I want is to be able to post a multi-line data containing any characters. I mean data from RichTextBox1 WITHOUT formatting, just simple text but from RichTextBox.

Comment: I have questions : Is it possible to change the JSON body to HTML one?  and If there's JSON, does it mean that the Web Site is built in JavaScript?